# BizTalk WCF Service and Common Schema Application

Tags: biztalk

I created a BizTalk WCF Service in BizTalk that uses a common schema. The issue is when I send a request to the service, I receive a security error. The site is anonymous authentication.

I removed the reference to the common schema and added the schema files to the BizTalk WCF service project and redeployed. I didn't receive any errors. I would think that since the BizTalk application that is transformed into a web service, has a reference to a common schema, it would be able to access it.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Comment: Was the Common Schema deployed to BizTalk?

Comment: yes, it was....